# Android: FileProvider IllegalArgumentException Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to save an image to the internal storage and I am facing:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.example/app_images/f9732a4a-a22e-4b62-b9b3-e546c8edc93c.jpg.
       at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
       at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
       at com.example.example.fragments.PhotosFragment.createImageFile(PhotosFragment.java:182)
       at com.example.example.fragments.PhotosFragment.dispatchTakePictureIntent(PhotosFragment.java:191)
```

Java code:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getActivity());
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!directory.exists())
        directory.mkdirs();
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath = new File(directory,UUID.randomUUID().toString() +".jpg");
    if(!mypath.exists())
        mypath.createNewFile();
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",mypath);
    return mypath;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() throws IOException {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        return;
    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",createImageFile());
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

My path code:

```
  <files-path name="my_images" path="app_images/"/>
```

My manifest code:

```
          <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.example.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Any clues on this?

Comment: `FileProvider` cannot serve from arbitrary locations, such as custom directories created by `getDir()`. Either store your files in a more common location (as Stanislav suggests), write an extension for [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) that can serve from there, or create your own `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 2):

You are stored file in private directory [`cw.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDir(java.lang.String,%20int))
Choose another available sollution described in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles)